# How can I use git reset for editing old commits

Tags: git, git-reset

1) Is there a way to edit or squash commits without using the Interactive mode of git rebase?
2) How do `git reset --keep` and `git reset --merge` work and how do they differ? I have read the git book, but I do not understand it yet...

Comment: Why do you not want to use interactive rebase?

Comment: Just run one command without opening the text editor. That's why

Comment: There's no better alternative. You can replicate all the commands and operations that git rebase does, but that's vastly more work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
git reset --soft <commit>
git commit -m "squashed"
```

to squash all commits between your current `HEAD` and `<commit>`.

The `git reset` part undos all commits that came after `<commit>` but will keep the changes staged (you can check this with `git status`). The subsequent `git commit` will commit all those staged changes as a single commit.